# XAML Binding not reflecting changes in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have the following code:

`MoviePanel.xaml`

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Black">
            <DockPanel Width="350">
                <StackPanel  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="200">
                    <TextBlock Width="200" Height="50" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} ({1})">
                                <Binding Path = "_selectedMovie.title"/>
                                <Binding Path = "_selectedMovie.year"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="200">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image Source="star_icon.png" Width="100"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding _selectedMovie.rating}" Style="{StaticResource AnnotationStyle}" Width="150"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>
        </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

`MoviePanel.xaml.cs`

```
public MoviePanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _moviePanelVM = new MoviePanelViewModel();
        _moviePanelVM.GetAllMovieDetails();            
        this.DataContext = _moviePanelVM;            
    }
```

`MoviePanelViewModel.cs`

```
 public class MoviePanelViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    // List to hold movieDetail objects 
    public List<MediaDetail> _movies { get; set; }

    public MediaDetail _selectedMovie { get; set; }

    public string selectedMovieID { get; set; }

    GetSelectedMovieDetails()
    {
       // Set _selectedMovie here
    }
```

`MediaDetail`

```
public class MediaDetail : DependencyObject {

    public ImageSource image {get; set;}        
    public string title {get; set;}
    public string year { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string rating { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string[] cast{ get; set; }
    public string[] director { get; set; }
    public string[] genre { get; set; }
    public string votecount { get; set; }
    public string[] language { get; set; }
    public string runtime { get; set; }
    public string part { get; set; }
    public string tagline { get; set; }

    public bool isMovieSelected
    {
        get { return (bool)this.GetValue(isMovieSelectedProperty); }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(isMovieSelectedProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty isMovieSelectedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                                                             "isMovieSelected", typeof(bool),
                                                             typeof(MediaDetail));

}
```

The problem I am having is that my `UI` is not being updated. That is `_selectedMovie.title`, `_selectedMovie.year` and `_selectedMovie.rating` are not being updated.

In another part of my `XAML`, I bind to `_movies` and this seems to work fine.

Would anyone have any ideas as to why this might be the case?

Thank you for your help.

**UPDATE:**

Based on the accepted answer below I changed:

`MoviePanelViewModel.cs`

```
 public class MoviePanelViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
      private MediaDetail _selectedMovie;
    public MediaDetail SelectedMovie
    {
        get { return _selectedMovie; }
        set
        {
            _selectedMovie = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedMovie");
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of that actually is *using* `INotifyPropertyChanged` (ie, raising the `PropertyChanged` event), so the UI can't receive the updates.

In particular, `MediaDetail` doesn't even derive from `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so when you bind to its properties, there is no way it will pick up the updates:

```
<!-- Binds to properties of MediaDetail! -->
<Binding Path = "_selectedMovie.title"/>
<Binding Path = "_selectedMovie.year"/>
```

For any property whose changes need to propagate to the UI, make sure it raises `PropertyChanged` and the UI will update as expected.

Comment: Thanks Bradley. I did as you suggested and it appears to be working now. I also added the `PropertyChanged` value for `_selectedMovie`. I just have one question.. should I change my `Dependency Property` to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` too? They seem to achieve the same purpose?

Comment: @Giri The Dependency property *uses* INPC, the backing property is actually not used by the CLR. Thus, you don't need to do that.